# Python Scipy fsolve function returns roots which are equal to starting points

Tags: python, scipy, root, equation

I need to get all roots of a scalar equation. But fsolve can only return 1 root for each call. So I design a self-call function `find_root_recursively` of fsolve. This function  will call itself until the new root is equal the previous root, which means `fsovle` has found all roots and no more new roots will be added. I use this logic to end self calling. But in some cases `fsolve` will return a root which is exactly the same as starting point. `one_root` = `start` always. Obviously this `start` is not a root. So the `list_root` is always adding new roots, it never ends.

```
    min_value = df_group['strike'].min()
    start_point = int(float(min_value) * 0.8)
```

```
def find_root_by_small_step(function, start_0, increment):
                    start = start_0
                    one_root = fsolve(function, start)
```

```
def get_transaction_data(self, expiry_date, df_group):
    return df_group[df_group['expiration_date'] == expiry_date].loc[(df_group['type'] == 1) & (df_group['position'] == 1)], \
           df_group[df_group['expiration_date'] == expiry_date].loc[(df_group['type'] == 1) & (df_group['position'] == 0)], \
           df_group[df_group['expiration_date'] == expiry_date].loc[(df_group['type'] == 0) & (df_group['position'] == 1)], \
           df_group[df_group['expiration_date'] == expiry_date].loc[(df_group['type'] == 0) & (df_group['position'] == 0)]

def calculate_one_payoff(self, stock_price, df_long_call, df_short_call, df_long_put, df_short_put):
    # buy call

    df_buy_call_executed = df_long_call[stock_price >= df_long_call['strike']]
    if len(df_buy_call_executed) > 0:
        buy_call_executed_sum = ((stock_price - df_buy_call_executed['breakeven_price']) * df_buy_call_executed['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        buy_call_executed_sum = 0

    df_buy_call_noExec = df_long_call[stock_price < df_long_call['strike']]
    if len(df_buy_call_noExec) > 0:
        buy_call_noExec_sum = (-1 * df_buy_call_noExec['option_price'] * df_buy_call_noExec['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        buy_call_noExec_sum = 0

    # sell call
    df_sell_call_executed = df_short_call[stock_price >= df_short_call['strike']]
    if len(df_sell_call_executed) > 0:
        sell_call_executed_sum = ((df_sell_call_executed['breakeven_price'] - stock_price) * df_sell_call_executed['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        sell_call_executed_sum = 0

    df_sell_call_noExec = df_short_call[stock_price < df_short_call['strike']]
    if len(df_sell_call_noExec) > 0:
        sell_call_noExec_sum = (df_sell_call_noExec['option_price'] * df_sell_call_noExec['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        sell_call_noExec_sum = 0

    # buy put
    df_buy_put_executed = df_long_put[stock_price < df_long_put['strike']]
    if len(df_buy_put_executed) > 0:
        buy_put_executed_sum = ((df_buy_put_executed['breakeven_price'] - stock_price) * df_buy_put_executed['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        buy_put_executed_sum = 0

    df_buy_put_noExec = df_long_put[stock_price >= df_long_put['strike']]
    if len(df_buy_put_noExec) > 0:
        buy_put_noExec_sum = (-1 * df_buy_put_noExec['option_price'] * df_buy_put_noExec['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        buy_put_noExec_sum = 0

    # sell put
    df_sell_put_executed = df_short_put[stock_price < df_short_put['strike']]
    if len(df_sell_put_executed) > 0:
        sell_put_executed_sum = ((stock_price - df_sell_put_executed['breakeven_price']) * df_sell_put_executed['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        sell_put_executed_sum = 0
    df_sell_put_noExec = df_short_put[stock_price >= df_short_put['strike']]
    if len(df_sell_put_noExec) > 0:
        sell_put_noExec_sum = (df_sell_put_noExec['option_price'] * df_sell_put_noExec['option_amount']).sum()
    else:
        sell_put_noExec_sum = 0

    one_stock_price_sum = buy_call_executed_sum + buy_call_noExec_sum + sell_call_executed_sum + sell_call_noExec_sum + \
                          buy_put_executed_sum + buy_put_noExec_sum + sell_put_executed_sum + sell_put_noExec_sum
    one_stock_price_sum = float(one_stock_price_sum)
    return one_stock_price_sum

df_long_call, df_short_call, df_long_put, df_short_put = self.get_transaction_data(expiry_date, df_group)
```

find_root_by_small_step(function=calculate_one_payoff, start=start_point, increment=increment)

```
ticker  type    position    expiration_date strike  option_price    option_amount   breakeven_price
AAPL    1   0   2021-11-19  145.0000    5.1700  2500.0000   150.1700
AAPL    0   1   2021-11-19  145.0000    2.9700  2500.0000   142.0300
AAPL    0   1   2021-11-19  145.0000    2.7000  5000.0000   142.3000
AAPL    1   1   2021-11-19  145.0000    5.8500  5000.0000   150.8500
AAPL    1   1   2021-11-19  155.0000    1.6000  1050.0000   156.6000

True root = 139.9 and 159.0
```

Comment: Please give example data where this happens: example function, example starting point etc.

Comment: i added sample data and my function. Plz help, thx